# Exception in thread "main" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException при изменении ArrayList

Tags: java

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(ArrayList.java:859)
at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:831)
at ru.mc.Bancomat.Main.main(Main.java:86)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
```

Объясните, из-за чего возможна ошибка?

Comment: Спасибо огромное. А насчёт switch не знал, я же начинающий, но посмотрю.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Мой модуль телепатии подсказывает, что вы пытаетесь изменять коллекцию когда перебираете её элементы. Например, так:

```
for (String s : listOfStrings) {
    listOfStrings.remove(s);
}
```

Так делать нельзя. Если вы хотите удалять элементы из коллекции во время перебора, то нужно явным образом использовать итераторы:

```
Iterator<String> it = listOfString.iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
    String s = it.next();
    it.remove();
}
```

**UPD**

Если внимательно почитать ваш код, то выяснится, что вы всё-таки изменяете коллекцию, пока перебираете её элементы. В вашем классе `Main` глобально объявлен список `users`, элементы которого вы перебираете, когда регистрируете нового пользователя:

```
for (User p : users) {
    int pincodreal = p.getPincod();
    if(pincodreal == pincod) {
        menu();
    } else System.out.println("Неверный пинкод");
}
```

Здесь вы вызываете метод `menu()`, в котором вызываете метод `exit()`, в котором, в свою очередь, зачем-то добавляете новый элемент в список `users`. В этот момент и происходит ошибка: пока вы перебираете элементы коллекции, нельзя добавлять или удалять из этой коллекции элементы. Поэтому либо выходите из цикла `for (User p : users)` прежде чем вызывать `menu()`, либо перепишите этот цикл с использованием итераторов.

И ещё: пересмотрите подход к организации меню. Все вложенные `if`-ы можно заменить на конструкции `switch`. Это упростит код для понимания и застрахует вас от потенциальных ошибок.

Comment: Я нигде не перебирал коллекцию, если как-то поможет, то я записываю данные с помощью сериализации и коллекции в файл.

Comment: @Nikneym, мой модуль телепатии может сбоить. Добавьте в вопрос код, в котором происходит данная ошибка, тогда мне не придётся гадать на кофейной гуще, пытаясь вам помочь.

Comment: Код - 200 строчек.
Судя по всему проблема в записи данных в файл.

Comment: @Nikneym, ну так выложите его на htp://pastebin.com/ или http://ideone.com/. Наши штатные экстрасенсы ещё не вышли из новогоднего запоя, а оставшиеся посетители форума телепатическими способностями не обладают!

Comment: http://ideone.com/3hv7nh

Comment: @Nikneym вы все-таки перебираете коллекцию в методе `main` (стр. 72) и модифируете коллекцию путем добавления к ней пользователя в методе `exit` (стр. 142 и 150).

Comment: Ну допустим, коллекцию я перебираю. Только вот в чём ошибка... А без добавления пользователя вроде же нельзя...

Comment: >Ну допустим, коллекцию я перебираю. Только вот в чём ошибка

вам вроде русским языом сказали: **вы модифицируете коллекцию**. Это и есть причина вашей ошибки